# adding array to other form controller in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, forms

I have an `event.controller.js` and `event.view.html`

In the controller I have event and guests, 
event is the form of multiple models and guests is 1 model with an array that I can pass more values too.

I have `localStorage` for events to save the form but guests array doesn't get passed into the form because they are seperated even though they're part of the same controller.

```
 function EventController($location, UserService, EventService, $rootScope, $http, FlashService) {
    var vm = this;

  vm.guests = [];


    vm.addGuest = function () {
        vm.guests.push(vm.newGuest);
    }

    vm.removeGuest = function (guest) {
        var index = vm.guests.indexOf(guest);
        vm.guests.splice(index, 1);
    }

    vm.event = event;


    function event() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        EventService.Create(vm.events)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    FlashService.Success('Event created successful', true);
                    $location.path('/events');
                } else {
                    FlashService.Error(response.message);
                    vm.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

my `event.view.html` looks like

```
  <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.event()" role="form">    
        <!--All my event input fields--> 
   <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
   </div>
  </form>
  <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.guest()" role="form">
   <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="guestform.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" ng-click="vm.addGuest()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Guest</button>
   </div>
    <div ng-repeat="guest in vm.guests track by $index" class="col-sm-6">
       {{guest}} - <a class="btn" ng-click="vm.removeGuest(guest)">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </form>
```

different forms submit to the same eventcontroller but are different model namespaces, how would I get a `vm.events.guest` array that is equal to the `vm.guests` after I add to it from the `vm.addGuest()` method?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you post the full source for the `EventController`?

Comment: @gnerkus when I click "add guest" I need it to pass every guest in guests to vm.event,  like vm.events.guests but that's not working. All my other models like vm.events.eventName or vm.events.firstName work.